# Get specific objects from an Array in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a static array something like

`[apple, banana, orange, lemon, goa, grapes, berry, mango, black grapes]`

with no changes in order(order will be fixed). Based on user selection dynamically i am getting two objects like `(orange, mango)`.

Now i need to fetch objects between these two objects i.e.`(lemon,goa,grapes,berry)` into a different array. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. First find index of both the values.
2. Then use array splice function to get the desired array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use slice() method to achieve this,

```
 var a = ['apple', 
             'banana', 
             'orange', 
             'lemon', 
             'goa', 
             'grapes', 
             'berry', 
             'mango', 
             'black', 
             'grapes']
    var d = a.slice(a.indexOf('orange') + 1, a.indexOf('mango'))
    console.log(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Cool Way

> ```
> var fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'lemon', 'goa', 'grapes', 'berry', 'mango', 'black', 'grapes'];
> var startingIndex  = fruits.indexOf('orange') + 1;
> var endingIndex  = fruits.indexOf('mango');
>
>
> fruits.splice(startingIndex, endingIndex -  startingIndex);
> ```